# How to run slow process async while simultaneously processing records as they become available

Tags: c#, asynchronous

My current code looks this. It works but it is slow. I am trying to speed things up but I do not have control over all the objects.

```
//This is a multi page PDF
var mergedOutput = CreateBaseDocument();

foreach (var item in selectedItems)
{
    //Slow running. processes on different server
    var doc = ExternalService.GetDocument(item.Id);

    //This can also be resource intense and runs on local server
    ThirdPartyComponent.AppendDocument(ref mergedOutput, doc);
}

return mergedOutput;
```

What I think would like to happen is ExternalService.GetDocument() to run async, adding the documents it returns into a queue or enumerable. Running in parallel I would like to have my thread calling AppendDocument as those objects become available from the ExternalService.

How would I go about the implementation. I am pretty new to running things async

Comment: Have a callback function (just any method, nothing special) that would run on the calling thread (the one that calls the async method) which would call the `AppendDocument` (make sure you dispatch it to the right thread) method, and call the callback function as records become available from the background thread.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu what if ThirdPartyComponent.AppendDocument(ref mergedOutput, doc); takes a longer time than expected and for some reason two calls to it overlap (notice the "ref")? I think OP has a better idea with queues, to guarantee that calls to AppendDocument do not overlap. IT IS simpler to just use a callback, but I found it risky and troublesome in many cases, especially when using components you have no control over that are not always "thread safe".

Comment: Seems like a perfect job for BlockingCollection/TPL/TPL Dataflow. Look for producer/consumer samples. Also, take care if you need to guarantee the final ordering you might want to switch to a for from the foreach, to pass in the index to the consumer as well.